# Errores al insertar registros usando EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo este método que recibe una lista de tipo `VentasLinias` y inserta cada registro en la BD

```
public void InsertLines(int idVenta , List<VentasLinias> listVentas)
{
    foreach (VentasLinias vl in listVentas)
    {
        db.VentasLinias.Add(vl);
        db.SaveChanges();
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Tengo 2 dudas sobre esto  la primera es, ¿el `SaveChanges()` lo realizo para iteración o al salir del bucle?

La otra duda es que cuando intento guardar me da este error:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' en EntityFramework.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: Error de validación para una o varias entidades. Vea la propiedad 'EntityValidationErrors' para obtener más detalles.

Si hago debug de la excepción veo esto pero no veo ninguna pista de que campo me está fallando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: Añade la excepción a la ventana watch para que veas cual es el error. Y por cierto el `SaveChanges` va afuera del foreach. Por otro lado, eso no puede ser todo el código, por ejemplo `idVenta` no es utilizado y no hay ninguna variable `i`. Si muestras mas se podría ver cual es el error,

Comment: Como comenta el amigo de arriba, no es para nada recomendable tener un db.SaveChanges() dentro de un bucle, ¿porque? por que cada vez que itera en el objeto/lista/array guarda los cambios, es decir: un objeto de 1000 items, lo itera y va, 1 saveChanges(), 2 SaveChanges(), 3 SaveChanges(). En tema de performance no es nada recomendable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El `db.SaveChanges()` debe ir fuera del `foreach`. La razon es que por cada llamada a `SaveChanges()`, EF crea una transacción y persiste los cambios pendientes en el contexto es decir si lo haces en cada iteración estará haciendo **n** conexiones a la BD en lugar de realizar solo una **única transacción** con todos los `INSERT`

Acerca del `EntityvalidationError` se debe a que tienes algun error de validación en la entidad que estas tratando de guardar, Si agregas el código de la clase `VentasLinias` podríamos ver cual es el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos muy amable.